# Contour Matplotlib from scatter data - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface

I am looking at data from some disk thicknesses and I am trying to plot it using matplotlib contour.

What I have allow me to produce something like this:

[image]

What I would like is something more like:

[image]

all I could find related to contour is Z being an equation, not scatter points.

maybe I need a completion/interpolation function to complete the missing parts.

here below some data for testing, I was not able to make something come out of the correct setup for the plt.contourf

Having it inside a circle is a nice to have, but not mandatory.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = pd.DataFrame({'X': [-9, -5, -5, -5, -3, -3, -3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9],
                      'Y':[0, -5, 0, 5, -3, 0, 3, -9, 0, 9, -3, 0, 3, -5, 0, 5, 0],
                      'Z':[5, 5.1, 5, 5, 5.4, 5.1, 5.3, 5.9, 5, 5, 5.3, 5.1, 5, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.]})
    
##%              
a_pivoted = a.pivot_table(index='Y', columns='X', values='Z')
ax = sns.heatmap(a_pivoted, annot=True)

##%
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.unique(a['X']), np.unique(a['Y']))
Z = a.pivot_table(index='Y', columns='X', values='Z').values

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
cp = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_title('Filled Contours Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('x (cm)')
ax.set_ylabel('y (cm)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

almost got it:

```
def ContourPlot(x, y, z, how_many_levels=17, title_plot='-', only_save=False): #read data from excel
if np.max(x) < 10:
    radius_wafer_edge = 10.
else:
    radius_wafer_edge = 100000.
# Create grid values first.
npts = 1000
xi = np.linspace(-radius_wafer_edge, radius_wafer_edge, npts)
yi = np.linspace(-radius_wafer_edge, radius_wafer_edge, npts)
# here it can be optimized still...
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None, :], yi[:, None]), method='linear')
# zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None, :], yi[:, None]), method='nearest')
# zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None, :], yi[:, None]), method='cubic')

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
cp = ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=how_many_levels, cmap="RdBu_r")
fig.colorbar(cp) # Add a colorbar to a plot
ax.set_title(title_plot)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set(xlim=(-radius_wafer_edge, radius_wafer_edge), ylim=(-radius_wafer_edge, radius_wafer_edge))
draw_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius_wafer_edge, fill=False)
ax.add_artist(draw_circle)
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
if only_save:
    plt.savefig(f'{title_plot}.png')
else:
    plt.show()
```

the first if takes you between my previous shared created test data, and with the real one you can get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAnYK.jpg

There is still some improvement to get the interpolation (extrapolation actually) to the edges of the wafer, but it is already good enough for my purpose.